# SQL Azure migration wizard taking long time

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, amazon-rds

I am using SQL Azure migration wizard for migrating one of my database to a different instance. It literally took more than 12 hours to do BCP out itself. The only change i have doneis to increase the packet size from 4096 to 65535(max). Is that wrong ? And i am doing this from a AWS server which is part of the same subnet where SQL server RDS instance is hosted

```
Analysis completed at 7/16/2016 1:53:31 AM -- UTC -> 7/16/2016 1:53:31 AM
Any issues discovered will be reported above.
Total processing time: 12 hours, 3 minutes and 14 seconds
```

Comment: You need to add more info,like database size,any log file.i have used the same tool,but migration depend on database size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [blog post from the SQL Server Customer Advisory Team (CAT)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2010/07/30/loading-data-to-sql-azure-the-fast-way/) that goes into a few details about optimal settings to get data into and out of Azure SQL databases.

#### Best Practices for loading data to SQL Azure

- When loading data to SQL Azure, it is advisable to split your data into multiple concurrent streams to achieve the best performance.
- Vary the BCP batch size option to determine the best setting for your network and dataset.
- Add non clustered indexes after loading data to SQL Azure.
- If, while building large indexes, you see a throttling-related error message, retry using the online option.